# If one question is a duplicate of 3 questions, why are these 3 questions not duplicates of each other?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently saw this question below

[image]

[How to round off to 2 decimal places for double variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087582/how-to-round-off-to-2-decimal-places-for-double-variables)

In this link we can see that the question is a duplicate of 3 other questions. Right? Then why are those 3 questions not duplicates of each other?

This question is the oldest one: [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java).

So why are the other questions not duplicates of the oldest one?

Comment: The literal answer is "because that's not how the duplicate system currently works." It might perhaps work better if it were changed

Comment: Please state your reasoning why you think the three possible duplicates should be duplicate of another question, who would select those duplicates, when, and why. It's really unclear why you would expect it to work as you say, and how. What you're seeing in this question is three different users having chosen three different possible duplicates for _this_ question, which does not have to mean they're all a duplicate of each other.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's means Now this system work and before it not working...

Comment: @CodeCaster he's likely suggesting a "network" type approach to duplicates - to make accessible *all* questions that were marked as a duplicate of the linked question, at once, in some kind of a list. The upside seems obvious - you'd have access to loads more dupes that may contain better information than the current one, instead of having to click through a (pretty much random) chain of dupes. Not sure whether it can be implemented well, though (and then thinking about any changes to the duplicate system is likely a waste of time anyway, as nothing is going to be implemented ever)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I understand, but they don't mention **why** they should be duplicates of each other, or how to determine that and when marking them as such would happen. That problem is not trivially solved.

Comment: @CodeCaster the "why" is easily answered IMO - access to a maximum of identical or similar questions. The "how" is indeed a problem though.

Comment: As you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065114/how-to-print-a-double-with-two-decimals-in-android   and  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java is duplicate because both have require `decimal Number`.

Comment: Yes, we understand. The question is how to fix this in a way that works. There's probably a thousand or more duplicates of that question out there. Should they all be duplicates of each other? You'd have a list of a thousand questions with the same content. See the problem?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I Agree with you. But Question As I found this 3 are the duplicate or not ??

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Pekka웃 If someone found duplicate question we have flag on it to duplicate and if the moderator as accept then confirm..

Comment: I suppose that is true, but what is your point?

Answer (score 9):

While for this case it would be fine to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065114/how-to-print-a-double-with-two-decimals-in-android) as a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java), it's entirely possible to think of a scenario where this is not the case.

Suppose you want to know what the maximum value of a standard integer is in a certain language called 'avaJ'. This question (A) might be closed as a duplicate of a question (B) asking for the maximum values of all numeric data types in 'avaJ'. But it might also be closed as a duplicate of a question (C) listing the differences between standard integer types among several languages, including 'avaJ'. Does that mean that (B) and (C) are duplicates of each other?

Or, viewing the questions as mathematical sets, A might overlap with both B and C, and the overlap is 'big enough' to answer A with B resp. C, while the overlap between B and C might be minimal (compared to what they cover).

[image]

Comment: I tell them all certain time ago..But no one can reponense as duplicate..

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry for my Bad English.. But I think now Glorfindel is explain what i said..

Comment: @CodeCaster Ok let gone this topic As The Figure showing I understand...

Comment: A Venn diagram says more than 1000 words ...

Comment: -1 for non-hand-drawn letters and use of unsanctioned colours ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus :) they would be unreadable with my handwriting. But I never heard about sanctioned colours - can you enlighten me?

Comment: The only sanctioned color is red.

Comment: @CodeCaster OK, then I'm usually complying, except for very good reasons.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to

Comment: @CodeCaster the well-upvoted [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138032/295232) uses blue & green markings as well :)

Comment: Umm... that diagram only shows that some questions are subsets of others. Of course, how to remove the last 3 characters and how to remove the last X characters are duplicates, but how to remove characters and how to remove characters and store them are not. Basically, if all possible answers to A are the same to B and the same to C then A, B, and C are duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question, why are they not duplicates, is that nobody flagged them as duplicates.

As described on [the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280773/why-do-some-questions-never-get-marked-as-a-duplicate-but-others-do/280777#280777), not all duplicates are noticed.  If they aren't noticed, they aren't flagged and they aren't marked duplicate.

The question you refer to was just unlucky.  Someone noticed that it was a duplicate.  The fact that three other questions were noted is unusual.  I suspect that, once one flag was raised, people started to look for duplicates.

There's nothing sinister in it.